# C# plotting chart- How to show maximum scale when set fixed interval at same time

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I am trying to plot a MSchart with setting X axis both maximum property and a fixed interval. But the chart I plotted is not showing maximum scale(tickmark). Unless I use auto interval instead of fixed interval.

---

If I just set X axis Maximum value and auto interval, the max scale is showing.(But the interval is not what i want)

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = dt.Rows[LastPointIndex].Field<double>("X");
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```

[image]

If I add this, the maximum scale is not showing.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0.15;
```

[image]

BTW, I add points in this way:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= index; j++)
{
double x = dt.Rows[j].Field<double>("X");
double y = dt.Rows[j].Field<double>("Y");
colomun1.Points.AddXY(x, y);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you included code that creates and populates a chart with the data you are trying to display.

Comment: @Steve Wellens: I added graphs.Thanks.